# using package of another project

Tags: android, eclipse

am trying to run the example of an ocr android project i downloaded from internet... it says in imports

```
import microsoft.hawaii.sampleappbase.HawaiiBaseApplication;
```

which is the package in another android project added to my eclipse work space.. how do i make this work? another thing is that in the properties of the project it has been mentioned android-16! and it says unable to resolve target "android-16" until the sdk is loaded!

```
package microsoft.hawaii.sampleapp.ocrservice;

import microsoft.hawaii.sampleappbase.HawaiiBaseApplication;

/**
*
*/
public class OcrApplication extends HawaiiBaseApplication {
    /**
 * Gets current authentication type
 * 
 * @return AuthenticationType
 */
@Override
public AuthenticationType getAuthType() {
    return AuthenticationType.GUID;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do i make this work?

Add the JAR to your project's `libs/` directory.

> another thing is that in the properties of the project it has been mentioned android-16! and it says unable to resolve target "android-16" until the sdk is loaded!

Download the Android 4.1.2 SDK Platform from your SDK Manager (see highlighted line in following screenshot):

[image: Android SDK Manager]

Comment: done with the android-16 error! installed the sdk! could u please edit your answer and guide to add the package from another project? i mean it is not the jar file i want to use as ref! its the class!

Comment: @Haroon: The class is in a JAR file, presumably. Microsoft should be providing you with instructions for how to obtain their library and add it to your project.